# FATAL error when use ASTRA theme on my localhost that is

Tags: themes, fatal-error

when i install astra theme and when i active it than my site look like crashed and it gives me given error, i am just using a localhost. anyone know about it ?
C:\xampp\htdocs\itsosmos\wp-includes\widgets.php on line 1265

Comment: can you clarify your question ?

Comment: you can edit your question no need to write all logs as an asnwer